# Elastic Beanstalk .ebextensions security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-beanstalk

I've been pouring over the AWS documentation for Elastic Beanstalk and .ebextensions.  Unfortunately, it's left me seeing stars.

I'm trying to accomplish a few things:

- I have a Java application that will deployed into multiple instances, each instance with a different environment variable passed in to the application.  Is there a way to accomplish this via Beanstalk (i.e. have a single application deployed multiple times with a different variable for each)?  Or do we need to move over to something like Opsworks?
- Each instance may need to have its own autoscale group.
- Each instance needs to have a different instance type.
- Each instance should be deployed to an **already existing** security group.  Everything I have found shows deployment to a new security group, I can't find how to launch the instance into an existing security group from within a .config file.

So, my first question is, can anyone provide some example code in .config file format that I can use to implement the above?  I'm not asking for anything complete, but something that can guide me.

Finally, I have spent hours going through the documentation and despite multiple references to listings of available config options, I can't seem to find it.  I found the "general" options, but I don't see where it tells you which section of the config file to put it into, syntax, etc.

Can anyone enlighten me?  Is there a master listing with API-like documentation of what the available config options are?

Comment: Having the same problem :/

Comment: I guess this may not be possible. However if you only need one master fullfilling a specific task, you may consider using the `leader_only: true` option.

Comment: You can’t use different instance type within the same beanstalk environment. To deploy beanstalk with existing sg you can use SecurityGroups option in Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration